# What are the causes of a cat jumping off a roof?

Tags: cats, health, injury

Currently my cat is in serious condition and I was wondering: what happens if a cat fell from a high height, aka a roof?

Comment: what type of injuries does your cat have,and please add more information like gender and age.

Comment: The title doesn't agree with the question in your post. Are you asking why a cat might jump off a roof? Or are you asking what harm it would suffer if it did?

Comment: she has a stroke and she is 16 cat years old

Comment: what harm would it suffer

Answer (score 3):

Lots of things can make a cat fall/jump of a roof.

- Getting scared.
- Hunting attempts, for example trying to catch a bird.
- Overestimating his/her abilities.
- Getting distracted.

Cats can get hurt if the fall is too short, because they haven't enough time to righten themselves.

A cat can get hurt if it is overweight and it falls from great height.

Wanting to get down but landing wrong can cause injuries, this is most common in kittens and very young cats.

Additional information: often cats that fall from tall buildings have a greater survival rate and less injuries than cats falling from lower buildings.

Comment: she has a stroke. I researched something from a website and it said it might have cause it